# How to receive current routes response in angular CLI?

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli, angular-components

Using angualar cli and nodejs for single app, passportjs configured in nodejs, node gives user data and returns Object with angular port, how to receive this response in angular routes at `ngOnInit()` ?

Redirect URL : `http://localhost:4200/api/pauth?code=4%2FAAAOF7UrUC...`

I have same route in angular too `/api/pauth` to access data.

Response for above URL (from nodejs):

`{"status":"0","message":"Looged in successfully","user":{"_id":"5a797783cb91253f8c667232","email":"example@gmail.com","password":"ya9.GltZBYvinL7N6D6OvgQ1z2Poa7ceOO3TS7LQB-CcsT3","authType":"google","createdAt":"2018-02-06T09:38:11.965Z","updatedAt":"2018-02-06T09:38:11.965Z","__v":0}}`

component.ts:

```
constructor(private http:Http, private router:Router,private httpc: HttpClient) { }

ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.router.url);
    this.http.get(this.router.url).subscribe(res => {
      this.posts = res;
      console.log(this.posts);
    });
}
```

Comment: is it making a API call? @151291

Comment: @rohith - Angular making api call to nodejs. both angular and nodejs following routes. and getting response in browser for above url, but do not know how to receive it in components.

Comment: you want to get value from the url?

Comment: in browser url you getting a data? but when you make an api call through angular you are not getting? check in network whether api calls are happening?

Comment: @rohith - getting object data by browser url all time.

Comment: when you are calling `this.http.get(this.router.url).subscribe(res => {
      this.posts = res;
      console.log(this.posts);
    });` what are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

i will tell solution with httpclient and i hope you imported httpclient module in app.module.ts

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
   let headers = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
   this.options =headers;
}
ngOninit(){
   this.getdata().subscribe(data=>{console.log(data)})
}
getdata(){
   this.http.get<any>(url,
     {headers:this.options,responseType:"json",observe:"response"})
     .map(res =>res.body)
}
```

Comment: current URL has the response, so is it require to add manually ?

Comment: no, you have to set headers cause your request returns json

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution :

Object response not accessible while the two ports are mingled, need to redirect from Node JS with params, now able to handle angular routes.

Example from node - **api.js** :

```
var code = req.user._id;
var url = 'http://localhost:4200/pauth?id='+code;
res.redirect(url);
```

Comment: what is this? part of your question?

Comment: if so, please put this in your question, not here.

Comment: @juancab - its my alternate solution while not able to access the response.